# Class Function within Parameter

Tags: java, c#

I might be having a brainfart here, and I probably am, however it's somewhat hard to word my problem, so I'm having some issues finding help.

---

Essentially, in Java, you can do something like this:

```
// create some generic class
public class Test {
   public void random() {}
}

// other class
public class Test2 {
   public Test2() {
      someFunction(new Test() {
         public void random() {
            System.out.println("howdy");
         }
      });
   }

   private someFunction(Test t) {
      t.random();
   }
}
```

I'm looking to convert this idea (modifying the contents of a class while passing it as a variable) into C#. I understand it can be done with *lambda expressions*, however I cannot for the life of me seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't do something like that in Java: the call to `someFunction` would need to be in a method. Notwithstanding that, which bit of the "something" are you actually asking about: the Test class, the Test2 class, the anonymous class, the random method, the someFunction method...?

Comment: Being able to modify the contents of random() while calling the method.

Comment: Which one is "the method"? And how are you modifying the "contents of random()" in this code?

Comment: In the class Test, the random function does nothing. When I pass an instance of Test to someFunction(), I edit the contents of random().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you are trying to achieve, but you could do it this way. Replace the property with an [`Action` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Test
{
    public Action random { get; set; }
}
```

And use like this:

```
var test = new Test 
{
    random = () => Console.WriteLine("Howdy")
};

test.random();
```

The delegate in this case is for a method that takes no parameters and has no return. If you wanted parameters you could use generic versions of `Action`. For example, if you need to pass an `int`:

```
public Action<int> random { get; set; }
```

Or if you wanted to return a value, then you would have to use `Func<>`:

```
public Func<int> random { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Cheers, mate.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Aye, it accomplishes the task.

Comment: What if you have to pass a variable, and also return a variable?

Comment: Then still use `Func` but give it 2 type parameters e.g.: `Func<string, int>`